# Is there an equivalent of Androids ShowcaseView for iOS?

Tags: ios, showcaseview

There is a project for Android on Github:

https://github.com/amlcurran/Showcaseview

**According to the readme:**

The ShowcaseView library is designed to highlight and showcase specific parts of apps to the user with a distinctive and attractive overlay. This library is great for pointing out points of interest for users, gestures, or obscure but useful items.

I would like to know if a functionally equivalent one exists for iOS. It would be useful to give users a quick tour of an app. Typically app intros are handled with a few swipe screens. Think Uber and Duolingo.

Google and Stackoverflow searching returns nothing meaningful. If I had time I'd work on this as a side project.

Edit: I've ended up using github.com/IFTTT/RazzleDazzle which works for both Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also try https://github.com/rahuliyer95/iShowcase this is a similar implementation of ShowcaseView for Android on iOS.

Answer (score 5):

You can also check out my implementation at https://github.com/scihant/CTShowcase

It's developed using Swift 2.0 and can also draw animated highlights such as this one:

**Update:**

It's now updated for Swift 3.0

[image]

Comment: It has compatibility issues with latest latest swift and other pods.

Answer (score 4):

You can check a small library ([MaterialShowcase on Github](https://github.com/aromajoin/material-showcase-ios)) that I created when developing my company app.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a framework we've been working on that might be useful, [BubbleShowCase](https://github.com/ECLaboratorio/BubbleShowCase-iOS). Check it out and don't hesitate to leave any feedback.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [**WSCoachMarksView**](https://github.com/workshirt/WSCoachMarksView). It is very easy to use, e.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[DDCoachMarks](https://github.com/ddoria921/DDCoachMarks) is a simple and flexible iOS alternative:

[image]