# Implement feature like showcase view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add `Demo Tips` for the `First Time after installation`

I want to show tips Like:

- Tap here for Task 1.
- Pinch Image to Image Scale & Rotation.
- Swipe Left for Menu, etc., etc.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225069/is-there-an-equivalent-of-androids-showcaseview-for-ios) & [This](https://github.com/workshirt/WSCoachMarksView) are similar to what I want.

All I have seen until now only supports tap, but I want to support all gestures (such as pinch, rotate, pan, swipe, etc.)

So, is there a "Better way" to support all gestures? Or any other library which can be used for this purpose in ObjectiveC?

Comment: @ Sneha Dudhat  show us what you have tried...thank you

Comment: @StanlyMoses Till now i have done Paging for app tutorial like [this](http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/UIPageViewController-Tutorial-Screen.jpg).. It works fine but now am finding something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/84op4.png)....

Comment: All i have seen till now is just support tap But i want support for all gestures in tutorials like pinch, rotate, pan, swipe etc